# Php unable to load firebird dynamic library

Tags: php, firebird

I have this problem, but the library it's on my ext folder.

[image: Capture of the problem]

I changed the php.ini file adding the driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `php_pdo_firebird.dll` is only an interface between PHP and the firebird engine. So you need firebird installed and also the `php-pdo-firebird.dll` needs to be able to find `fbclient.dll`

Try copying `fbclient.dll` into `\wamp\bin\php\php7.1.10`

If you also need access from Apache you may need to copy `fbclient.dll` into `\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\bin` as well and also amend the `php.ini` file that controls PHP under apache. Do that by using the wampmanager menus to edit the correct `php.ini` file like this

```
left click wampmanager icon -> PHP -> php.ini
```